# Drag and Drop in angular 2 using ng2-drag-drop

Tags: javascript, angular

I am implementing a requirement where i need to perform the drag and drop functionality .

I found this on GitHub

> https://github.com/ObaidUrRehman/ng2-drag-drop

and implemented the same. But, there is a little modification i need to do here,
there are two zone one is drag and the other is drop.

In drop i have different element let say i need to perform the drop operation only on the selected item not on the non-selected item.

[image]

Like in the picture i have selected the carrot container i sould allow drop only on the carrot container not on onion and potato.

Please suggest me.

Comment: I' m getting a little confused about `only on the carrot container not on onion and potato`. what did this mean?

Comment: @Pengyy there are there div inside each dice item are placed . and we can drop on those div. We want to enable drop only on the selected div i.e: carrot in the above case.

Comment: I got my solutuon.